# Meterpreter pivot with a bind_named_pipe

Tags: meterpreter, smb, pivoting

I have a pivot setup on a compromised windows 10 box and am trying to get an SYSTEM shell on a separate machine in the target network. I have successfully done this abusing an unquoted service path via a `meterpreter/reverse_named_pipe` that connects to my pivot but can this be done using `bind_named_pipe`? I may be thinking of it wrong but I want my pivot meterpreter shell to connect to the `bind_name_pipe` that is now running as listener via the abused service. In this scenario I don't think I would be able to use a `multi/handler` because my attacking machine doesn't have direct access to the target machine unless through the pivot. Or am I thinking about this wrong? Is the `multi/handler` aware of the pivot and will use it to access the target network?

Comment: It's possible to get the bind connection via HTTP tunnel

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Meterpreter, you can set up port forwarding (or even routing) through your existing sessions. Then, when you want to connect to another host on that network, you can point your multi/handler at the tunnel entrance or route.